# This binding in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I am puzzled by some node.js behaviour, which is different fron Google Console.

Here is a  simple code

```
var t = "GLOBAL";
var objet = {
  t : "LOCAL1",
  test : function() {
    console.log(this.t,t);
  }
};
var objet2 = {
  t : "LOCAL2",
  test : objet.test
};
var test = objet.test;
objet.test();
objet2.test();
test();
```

This code yiels different result.

In node.js, i have these results :

```
LOCAL1 GLOBAL
LOCAL2 GLOBAL
undefined 'GLOBAL'
```

In chrome console :

```
LOCAL1 GLOBAL 
LOCAL2 GLOBAL 
GLOBAL GLOBAL
```

I thought that calling directly the function binded to test.t, this would be binded to the global scope, it is the case in chrome, but node in node.js.

Note that if i remove the `var`in the first line, the node.js version give the same result.

So what is going one ? It seems that there is a scope in node.js that i am missing ?
Does somebody have a clue ?

Comment: This is not an issue it about scope in javascript, you're calling a function from global scope and "T" does not exits on global scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NodeJS, the default scope is that of the module. Global scope is even bigger than the module, which is what `this` refers to. In Chrome, the global scope is `window`, which is what `this` is.

See the [module](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) documentation and more importantly, [globals](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html).

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. Seems evident now :)

Comment: Just as an addition: node.js wraps `(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { /*the source of the file*/ });` around the source when including. So the `var` is in the scope of that anonymous function.

Comment: @t.niese Does Node itself do that, or is that just how it's compiled for browserify?

Comment: That's something nodejs does internally. If you look at its source (`src/node.js`)  there is a `NativeModule.wrapper` containing `['(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ', '\n});']` and a `NativeModule.wrap` function doing `return NativeModule.wrapper[0] + script + NativeModule.wrapper[1]`, this wrap function is called for every file that is included using `require`. That's the same what you would do by hand if you use e.g. AMD in the browser.